# Python web scraping - timeout_ConnectTimeoutError_MaxRetryError_ConnectTimeout

Tags: python, timeout

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to scrape sofifa to get an historical info on football players on fifa.

I wrote some lines of code following a tutorial. The code works fine till I get some errors (timeout, ConnectTimeoutError, MaxRetryError, ConnectTimeout).

I tried to solve the error adding `timeout=10` in the `request.get` but this does not solve the problem? Does anyone know what is the problem and how to solve it?

```
def soup_maker(url):
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    markup = r.content
    soup = bs(markup, 'lxml')
    return soup
```

- timeout - timeout: timed out
- During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ConnectTimeoutError ConnectTimeoutError:
>   (, 'Connection to sofifa.com timed out. (connect
>   timeout=10)')

- During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> MaxRetryError MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sofifa.com',
>   port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /player/237678/ibrahima-konate/19/159523/ (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to sofifa.com timed out.
>   (connect timeout=10)'))

- During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ConnectTimeout ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sofifa.com',
>   port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /player/237678/ibrahima-konate/19/159523/ (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to sofifa.com timed out.
>   (connect timeout=10)'))